# Clang Error "duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

This error is listed a lot over stack and the common fixes don't seem to work for me. I am getting the error: "duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64" when compiling an Obj-C MacOS Xcode App. Xcode 11.5 and MacOS Catalina 10.15.5. It is saying there are 15 duplicate symbols, with one of the 15 errors looking like:

```
duplicate symbol '_visual10Window' in:
    /Users/tempuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-cdicjztmkktfomehwaphnzhbozgh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug/test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Test.o
    /Users/tempuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-cdicjztmkktfomehwaphnzhbozgh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/test.build/Debug/test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MainView.o
```

My MainView.h and MainView.mm do not contain any definition for visual10Window.

My Test.h has (removing this give a use of undeclared identifier error).

```
@class Visual10;
Visual10 *visual10Window;
```

and Test.mm includes

```
#import "Visual10.h"
```

and I'm calling a xib from a menu item in Test.mm

```
- (void)Visual10Menu:(id)sender {
 if (!visual10Window) {
 visual10Window = [[Visual10 alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"Visual10"]; }
[visual10Window showWindow:self]; }
```

I have tried the common suggestions including:

- Install and reinstall pods (this project doesn't use pods)
- Checked for wrong imports like import ".m" instead of ".h"
- Remove -all_load from Other Linker Flags
- Build Settings / No Common Blocks set to NO
- Checked for duplicate files Build Phases / Compile Sources (None)
- Tried adding and removing -ObjC from Other linker flag
- Tried Build Settings / Enable Testability set to NO
- Tried clearing derived data

None of these work and still get duplicate symbol errors.

Comment: It is possible you do have duplicate symbols. In order to help people help you edit your question (don't add the information in a comment) to include the definition of `visual10Window` in `Test` and `MainView` (in source and any headers). Also add the versions of macOS and Xcode being used and whether any builds (Run, Archive etc.) work. Given that information somebody will undoubtedly help you out.

Comment: The compiler is telling you that both `Test.o` and `MainView.o` both define the symbol `_visual10Window`. It may not be obvious, but something in `MainView.mm` is declaring this symbol again, and in my experience it's usually a static variable declaration (`Type var;`) in an `.h` file that really should be an external reference (`extern Type var;`). The problem being that every file that includes that header declares its own copy of the variable.